# Minimum Value based on difference

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to set my minimum value in my textbox quantity. I want to get the difference of two columns int (Quantity - Critical Level). How could the difference of the two numbers be the minimum of the textbox

Eg: AB products has a critical level of 25, but my quantity is only 10.
The difference of 15 is the minimum value of the textbox. I should not able to save int that are lower than 15.

I'm using this select statement, but I could not set it into the minimum value of the textbox

SELECT ABS(Inventory.Quantity - SupplierProducts.CriticalLevel) AS Minimum FROM Inventory

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please edit your question and describe the scenario properly, add what you have tried, where you are facing issues. Also add some sample data. Start here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ArghyaC I have edited the question, was it not still clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could help you , rangeValidator

have a look at this link: [rangeValidator](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showasp.asp?filename=demo_rangevalidator2)

can you try this code
//I assume you already have the values of Quantity and Critical Level

```
protected void setMinimumValue()
{
    int minimumValue= (Quantity - CriticalLevel);
    //The id of your RangeValidator
    RangeValidator1.MinimumValue = minimumValue;
}
```

//in aspx

```
<asp:RangeValidator runat="server" id="RangeValidator1" controltovalidate="txtMinimumValue"  errormessage="Please enter a valid number!" />
```

Comment: This is somehow similar, but the minimum is not set by fixed no. It must based its minimum on the difference of the two columns

Comment: did you try it? in using rangeValidator specify the textBox in which you will place the minimum value from your query. 
controltovalidate="yourTxtBoxId"

Comment: It does not show any error but it does not work. it still keeps on adding below the minimum. I'm trying to use MinimumValue='<%# Eval("Minimum") %>' on aspx, but it is not working, but it is working in a listview.. Any suggestion?

Comment: can you show your code? I suggest set the minimum value in code behind. rangeValidtor1.MinimumValue = resultFromYourQuery ;

Comment: If you want, remove the rangeValidator. Create a hidden Field and set the value from your query, then compare two values of your textbox and the hidden field and prompt if the value of textbox is lower than the value of the hidden field.